# Can configure two DataSoure in a Spring configuration?

Tags: spring, jpa, mybatis

I am developing a web application and I need two DataSource to connect two difference database according to my requirement.One DataSource will use Spring + JPA framework and another DataSource is use Spring + MyBatis framework.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can I suggest manage both from spring and obtained from the applicationContext.

```
<bean class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" id="dataSource" >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
```

```
   <bean class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" id="dataSourceOrderDetail" >
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url.orderdetail}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
  </bean>
```

Just need to have different name of id, to be properly injected

Check [this](http://www.javabeat.net/spring-ibatis-integration/) to review how you can integrate spring with ibatis then configure beans using the datasource beans

Or if you want to use datasource-ds.xml just put the two datasource xml files in the lib folder within your application context, if you are using something like jboss or tomcat.

**UPDATE**

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.staples.sa.pricemart.repository.pag"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <qualifier value="pagTransactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.staples.sa.pricemart.repository.orderdetail"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactoryOrderDetail" />


<bean id="transactionManagerOrderDetail" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryOrderDetail" />
    <qualifier value="orderDetailTX" />
</bean>


<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactoryOrderDetail">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnitOrderDetail" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceOrderDetail" />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- -->
```

Persistence.xml need to look like this. (need to complete the xml config)

```
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

And

```
<!-- Add the persistence context for OrderDetail -->
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnitOrderDetail"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

Comment: Could you tell me please.So how about for spring transaction, it can handle for both of two datasource.

Comment: You need to have different transaction bean for the different database.

Comment: @PradeepKrKaushal Yes I think so.

Comment: There are two possibilities: either you use two transaction managers and have two separate transactions or you run in JEE container and use spring JTA transaction manager. In the latter case there will one [distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_transaction) transaction in which both datasources participate.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I updated my answer with the needed configurations, but yes you need to use 2 transaction manager

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code for you

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml", Main.class);
    DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ac.getBean("dataSource");
    DataSource mysqlDataSource = (DataSource) ac.getBean("mysqlDataSource");
```

Context.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle.devcake.co.uk:1521:INTL"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<bean id="mysqlDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://dbhost-prospring-psql/prospring"/>
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

<bean id="lobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler">
    <property name="nativeJdbcExtractor" ref="nativeJdbcExtractor"/>
</bean>

<bean id="nativeJdbcExtractor" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.CommonsDbcpNativeJdbcExtractor"/>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure as many databases as you like in Spring  context by declaring datasource beans with different id's and 
injecting appropriate properties from properties file.  if the two databases are different then you are in territory of distributed transactions and you must configure a [Spring transaction manager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/JtaTransactionManager.html) which can operate with JTA.  Also worth noting is that Spring transaction manager is merely an abstraction and it needs to have external JTA transaction 
manager configured (like [Bitrionix](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BTM/Spring+Framework) / [Atomikos](http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/SpringIntegration)) or if deploying under EE application server then transaction manager can be looked up in JNDI registry. Then when you mark the transaction boundary (perhaps using Spring Transactional annotation) then Spring would automatically co-ordinate the transactions.